# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'my_args'

Tags: python, python-2.x

How can I get access to `my_args` list data type in `__main__`?

**test1.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print 'main function'
    one()

def one():
    print 'one function'
    my_args = ["QA-65"]

def two():
    print 'two function'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    getattr(my_args, pop)
```

Comment: you never defined a global variable with that name. And that's not how you access a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you `return` them from `one()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print 'main function'
    args = one() # returns my_args, which i'm assigning to args
    print 'i got args from one():', args
    print args.pop()

def one():
    print 'one function'
    my_args = ["QA-65"]
    return my_args

def two():
    print 'two function'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #getattr(my_args, pop)
    # ^^^ Moved this up to main() ^^^
```

Outputs:

```
main function
one function
i got args from one(): ['QA-65']
QA-65
```

Comment: Haha, thanks. I avoid using `global` at all costs in exchange for explicitly returning values as needed.  Even having `main()` return the final expected output is a good idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this using `global`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print 'main function'
    one()

def one():
    print 'one function'
    global my_args
    my_args = ["QA-65"]

def two():
    print 'two function'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print my_args.pop()
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Di0eC).

**Just because you** *can* **doesn't mean you should!**